# Getting exception from scanner in the loop

Tags: java

I have a code that takes input from the user. Loop is required to keep asking if input is not in correct format. As long as input correct, program works fine. 
PS. It fails when user enters incorrect input.

> Exception: java.util.NoSuchElementException at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)

If I use `BufferedReader`, I have no issues. 
It only fails with `Scanner`.
Thanks for any clarifications.

```
public String getUserInput(String prompt) {
    String inputLine = null;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(true){
        inputLine = null;
        System.out.println(prompt + " ");

        inputLine = sc.nextLine();

        if(inputLine.length() == 2 &&
           inputLine.charAt(0) >= 'a' && inputLine.charAt(0)<='g' && 
           inputLine.charAt(1) >= '0' && inputLine.charAt(1)<='6'){
               break;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You entered your guess incorrectly.");
            System.out.println("Please enter your guesses with ranges a through g and 0 through 6.");
        }
    }
    sc.close();
    return inputLine.toLowerCase();
}
```

Comment: what is the input its failing with

Comment: And the exception is...?

Comment: This seems to work fine for me? What are you expecting?

Comment: if you enter correct format like a6, then it works fine, but if you enter 66, then it fails and supposed to ask again. but it throws an exception.

Comment: What exception? Pls update your question. For me your code works fine

Comment: regarding the https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()] your scanner does not find any new line.

Comment: I understand that, but how do I force it to wait for the next line? Do I need to use another method?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is a next line by doing: `sc.hasNext()` which returns true if there is. You should use this before calling `sc.nextLine()`